# snopping using developer options. keeps turning back on itself

Tags: android-10

I think my borther in law has gained access to my phone and written a admin app/ script to automatically turn on developer options. I have turned it off umpteen times and yet it turns itself back on.

can anyone think of how he can do this and what the solution to this is? It appears to do this regardless of having any form of connection to the internet/phone network. I removed the sim to establish this. I have tried to uninstall apps via adb but still.

Comment: Disabling developer options has no effect, it is just the menu. You can access this menu e.g. by certain apps even if it is not enabled. Or are you referring to the Android Debug Bridge (adb) that allows device access via USB?

Comment: adb bridge am referring to